# How does the DI resolution for @ContentChild(TOKEN) with a toke work in angular?

Tags: angular

I wanted to ask how the DI resolution works with @ContentChild when using a Token? How does angular know which instance it should inject in the parent? Does the DI-System go downwards when using @ContentChild? Would really appreciate any exmplenation :). I stumbled across this question when I tried to get the childcomponent which is projected with ng-content. E.g.

```html
<widget>
  <weather-widget-content></weather-widget-content>
</widget>

<widget>
  <velocity-widget-content></velocity-widget-content>
</widget>
```

I have the example form this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-MRJ9QYCvI&ab_channel=DecodedFrontend). In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gnnip3?file=src%2Fwidget%2Fwidget.component.ts) you can see it tailored to my usecase with an abstract base class. Here is a short overview of the code

```
// Baseclass
abstract class WidgetContentBase {
  public widgetTitle?: string;
  public randomNumber?: number;
}

// Token for registering the children in the DI-System
const WIDGET_CONTENT_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<WidgetContentBase>('widget-token');

// WidgetContainer where different Widgets that extend the Base can be rendered
export class WidgetComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public widgetTitle?: string;
  public randomNumber?: number;
  @ContentChild(WIDGET_CONTENT_TOKEN) widgetContent?: WidgetContentBase;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.widgetTitle = this.widgetContent?.title;
    this.randomNumber = this.widgetContent?.randomNumber;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}

// OneExample WidgeContent Component
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: WIDGET_CONTENT_TOKEN,
      useExisting: WeatherWidgetContentComponent,
    },
  ],
})
export class WeatherWidgetContentComponent
  extends WidgetContentBase
  implements OnInit
{
  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'Weather Widget';
  }
}
```